# union between two has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I use rails 4.1 with Postgres and I have a model like this one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  has_many :event_memberships
  has_many :shared_events, through: :event_memberships, source: event

  def all_events
    #... code goes here
  end
end
```

I'd like to do an union between events and shared_events associations but I can't make it work.

The only thing I can make it work is this:

```
def all_events
  events + shared_events
end
```

But it will execute 2 SQL queries instead of one and I won't be able to order or limit the results.

I have also tried something like this:

```
def all_events
  User.find_by_sql("(#{events.to_sql}) UNION (#{shared_events.to_sql})")
end
```

Or this method https://coderwall.com/p/9hohaa
But both methods throw this error:

```
PG::UndefinedParameter: ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
```

That seems to be known bug in rails 4+ and it won't be resolved https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13686

So my only option here seems to write plain old SQL.
Anyone with a better idea ?

Comment: I'm curious, what happens when you do this: `User.find_by_sql("(?) UNION (?)", events.to_sql, shared_events.to_sql)` ?

Comment: I can't make it work. It seems that the question mark interpolation returns a quoted string for the to_sql statement that SQL doesn't understand. `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'SELECT "events"`